# Joint density $X^2+Y^2$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, random-variables

Let's say we have a point $(x,y)$ in the unit circle.

I've read (without proof :( ) that the joint density of $z$, where $z^2=x^2+y^2$, is:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}\frac{2}{\pi}(x^2+y^2)&\mathrm{\ if \ } x^2+y^2\le1\\ 0&\mathrm{\ otherwise\ }\end{cases}$$
Can someone show me why?

Comment: What about accepting the answer? Two days is a decent delay and reading the comments it seems you got satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

What you say is (almost?) true if you say that you're random point in the circle is **uniformly distributed**.  That means the probability of falling within any region is proportional to the region's area.  The area of a circle centered at $(0,0)$ whose radius is $z$ is $\pi z^2$.  This is $\pi(x^2+y^2)$.  The probability of falling within that circle is therefore $\pi(x^2+y^2)$ divided by the area of the whole unit circle, which is $\pi$.  But notice you're talking about the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ (not to be confused with $x$ and $y$, not the density of $z$.  The **cumulative probability distribution function** (not the density function) of $Z=\sqrt{Z^2+Y^2}$ is therefore
$$
F_Z(z) = \begin{cases} z^2 & \text{if }0\le z\le1, \\  0 & \text{if }z<0, \\  1 & \text{if }z>1.  \end{cases}
$$
The density function is therefore
$$
f_Z(z) = \begin{cases} 2z & \text{if }0\le z\le1, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$

The joint density of the coordinates is
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1/\pi & \text{if }x^2+y^2\le1, \\ 0&\text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
Here you see the reason why the word "uniform" is used: the thing that's "uniform" is the density function, in this cases a constant $1/\pi$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have still two questions: 1)why is the joint density for $ Z = \sqrt{X^2+y^2} $ (attention, you wrote 2 times Z) (i.e. how do you get this?)
2)What would the joint density be for one coordinate, X for example? (and why and how do you get this?)

Comment: I was very careful to distinguish between capital $Z$ and lower-case $z$, using each where appropriate.  I didn't write $2Z$; I wrote $2z$.  It doesn't make sense to speak of a _joint_ density for $Z$, since $Z$ is only one scalar-valued random variable.  "Joint" is a word used when talking about two or more random variables.  How I got the cumulative distribution function for (capital) $Z$ is something I explained.  If that's what you're not understanding, can you be specific about where you get lost?

Comment: For the _density_ function of (capital) $Z$, denoted (lower-case) $f_Z$, I got that by differentiating the cumulative distribution function, denoted (capital) $F_Z$.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Last question: How do you get the cumulative probability distribution function $F_Z(z)$ ?

Comment: The random variable $Z=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ is the distance from $(0,0)$ to the random point $(X,Y)$ in the disk.  The c.d.f. $F_Z(z)$ is $\Pr(Z\le z)$, the probability that the distance is less than or equal to $z$.  The distance is less than or equal to $z$ precisely if the random point $(X,Y)$ is inside a disk of radius $z$ centered at $(0,0)$.  Therefore the probability is the area of that disk divided by the area of the whole disk in which the random point can lie, thus $\pi z^2$ divided by $\pi\cdot1^2$.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful.
I stated that it isn't clear to me why $f_{X,Y}$ is 1/pi. How do you get this constant?

Comment: The area of the whole circle is $\pi r^2=\pi\cdot1^2=\pi$.  Since it's a uniform distribution, probabilities are proportional to areas---for example, if one region within the disk has three times the area of another, it's three times as probable.  The probability of the whole disk must be $1$, and its area is $\pi$, so you have to multiply its area by $1/\pi$ to get the probability.  Since it's uniform, you multiply all areas by that same number, $1/\pi$.